# Split Pandas dataframe into multiple dataframes based on empty column delimiter

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm reading the following excel sheet into a dataframe.

[image]

I want to split it into three dataframes by product. The tables will always be delimited by a single blank column in between, but each table can have different number of columns.

Comment: Share this sample file please (dropbox, drive...) There are plenty of solutions.

Comment: You don't have to stick to Python and pandas, you can split it with Excel VBA in advance. For example, [Renge.CurrentRegion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.currentregion) can be used?

Comment: Perhaps this is the way to find empty columns? [Find and delete empty columns in Pandas dataframe](https://www.jitsejan.com/find-and-delete-empty-columns-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: @kunif - true but that option is currently not available as this sheet is externally auto generated - hence looking to do the processing python. also the aim is not to delete the columns but to split them into different dataframes for use later in the project - basically read all data at once - split into different dataframes and then use it later on without the cost of multiple calls to the excel file

Comment: @Corralien here you go: https://docs.google.com/file/d/1Xvs_C7DKL38Vcr14vMF5PkO4TQoquvWN/edit?usp=docslist_api&filetype=msexcel

Comment: The second article introduced has two functions. If you can find the empty columns using the first function, can you extract the DataFrame based on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the article introduced in the comment, you can process it as follows.

```
import pandas as pd

#### Read excel file to dataframe
df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', index_col=None, header=None)

#### Find empty column and listed
empcols = [col for col in df.columns if df[col].isnull().all()]
df.fillna('', inplace=True)

#### Split into consecutive columns of valid data
allcols = list(range(len(df.columns)))
start = 0
colslist = []
for sepcol in empcols:
    colslist.append(allcols[start:sepcol])
    start = sepcol+1

colslist.append(allcols[start:])

#### Extract consecutive columns of valid data and store them in a dictionary
dfdic = {}
for i in range(len(colslist)):
    wkdf = df.iloc[:, colslist[i]]
    title = ''.join(wkdf.iloc[0].tolist())
    wkcols = wkdf.iloc[1].tolist()
    wkdf.drop(wkdf.index[[0,1]], inplace=True)
    wkdf.columns = wkcols
    dfdic[title] = wkdf.reset_index(drop=True)

#### Display each DataFrame stored in the dictionary
dfkeys = dfdic.keys()
for k in dfkeys:
    print(k)
    print(dfdic[k])
    print()
```